# AWS Student Starter Pack Region Change

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using an AWS student pack provided by my university. I want to switch the location to Bahrain from N. Virginia. Everytime I try to do that I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Educate Starer Accounts are **very limited**.

You can check what is allowed in the link below:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf)

Shortly, you have **no access to billing** information and many, many other services and options.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to enter in the Billing area into the console to change to Bahrain.

What you have to do is:

1. Login on AWS Educate site (https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/)
2. Right Up corner (AWS Account) inside the AWS Educate portal
3. Click "AWS Educate Starter Account". It will open another tab, "Workbench".
4. Click to open "AWS Console"

Now, you are logged on AWS console.

Go to Services, select a services that changes with a region, for example, EC2, RDS, etc., if you see "Global" on right top corner, you cannot change the region to Bahrain, please select another service first, then select the region.

I hope I could help.

Comment: It shows N. Virginia as the region and when I try to change it then it becomes global. I'm guessing the account is under my university's domain and they might have some restrictions on the account.

Comment: Have you tried enter in another service first?  For example, EC2, RDS, DynamoDB... Then change the region to Bahrain.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but it seems the domain this account is under has restricted many features necessary for region change like billing information.

Comment: So probably yes @dr_nyt sorry about that, try to talk with the school admins. Have a great week.

Comment: Regardless, thank you for taking the time to answer :D